# Why does it print "None" when I input new values that are out of range? Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, loops

I was trying to write a code where if the user input is not within range, it would ask the user for the input again. This had worked the first time the loop is executed but after that, it prints "none". How do I keep the loop repeating until a valid answer is inputed? Can someone please explain this for me.

e.g if I input the number 5 to the code below, it should ask the user for again, until the user inputs a valid answer.

```
def find_letter(word):
    prompt = "Enter index: "
    index = int(input(prompt))
    length_of_word = len(word) - 1
    while (index >= 0 and index <= length_of_word):
        index_word = word[index]
        return index_word
    else:
        index = int(input(prompt))
print(find_letter("Cats"))
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please share with us your [minimal and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the logic backward. Currently, your code will (try to) keep running the content of the while block as long as the input is valid, though it won't since there's a return inside the while block. Meanwhile, the else block will be only run *once*. So you'll probably want

```
    while (index < 0 or index > word_length): #the 'invalid' input
        index = int(input(prompt)) #keep attempting to get new input
    else: #when we reach this block, the input is valid
        index_word = word[index] #so this is run once
        return index_word
```

Re-read your [Python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-while-statement). The first block of the while loop is run as long as the condition specified is true, and the else block (if any) is run only once when the condition is no longer true, except if the first block exit with return, break, or throwing an exception. It's possible the condition is already false before entering the while-else, so in that case the first block is *never* run, while the else block is still run once.

Comment: when implementing a while statement, should I always start with the "invalid" input first?
Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Yes, read the blocks as "let's keep doing this while it's true, and when it's not, continue with the else". Keep in mind other programming languages may lack the "else" part of while block, so it might confuse non-Python coder at first (like me). else block also won't be executed if you exit the loop with return (as you already did) or break.

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop is infinite as you do not increment the variable `index`. Also, the `else` statement must have an `if` before it. (*I suppose you meant to write `if` in place of `while`*)

Comment: how would I go about this, using while statements instead of if statements? What do you mean by incrementing a variable? Sorry I am new to Python.

Comment: by incrementing  I mean that you have to increase the value of index, only then will the loop terminate at some point by not staying in the input condition. You have to use if statement if you want to use else.

Comment: consider getting familiar with loops and conditional statements first.

Comment: @lunalilac consider reading [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/using-else-conditional-statement-with-for-loop-in-python/) , and [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/decision-making-python-else-nested-elif/)

Comment: @lunalilac consider upvoting or accepting the answer if it helped.

Comment: @NSR OP is not trying to write a for-else loop or if-else inside a loop, he's writing a [while-else](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-while-statement), index isn't meant to be incremented since the goal is to keep asking the user until it got the valid input.

Comment: @Martheen I am sorry I did not see that. If you are sure this is what is the motive of the code you should consider editing the question

Comment: "if the user input is not within range, it would ask the user for the input again" is already there on the question even before the edits. I'm guessing the while-else part catch you off guard, being rarely used (rightly so, the keyword name is misleading) even by seasoned Python dev and since OP is still learning, you guessed they're trying for the more common if-else inside for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the `None` returned, it happens because in the `else`, after the input, the function ends, implicitly returning a `None` (i.e. returning nothing).